# Views Count missing on modern communication page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, communication-site

I have the following problem:

The Views Count is missing on modern communication pages in my SharePoint Online tenant.

[image: views count missing]

Has anyone else experienced this? It is happening on every page in every site especially News Posts.

Could it be that this is some security/compliance setting in M365?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, i found the error: guest Accounts can't see the views count of an page.